# Objective-c - XMLReader not working correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml, xmlreader

I have a problem with the class XMLReader ( https://github.com/Insert-Witty-Name/XML-to-NSDictionary ).

When i parse this document, it's work perfectly

```
<webservices>
    <title>Photos</title>
    <item>
       <name>test</name>
    </item> 
    <item>
       <name>test2</name>
    </item> 
</webservices>
```

The programme display :

```
  webservices = {
        item = (
                  {
                    name= "test1.";
                  },
                  {
                     name= "test2";
                  }
              );
        title = Photos;
    };
}
```

But when i have one Item, it's doesn't work. I'm not a NSarray of Item but a NSDictionnary with directy the node "name".

```
<webservices>
    <title>Photos</title>
    <item>
       <name>test</name>
    </item> 
</webservices>
```

The programme display :

```
  webservices = {
        item =    {
                     name= "test";
                  }
        title = Photos;
    };
}
```

A idea ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal - if there is only one item, there's no need to wrap a single item in an array. Your handler just needs to get the `[webservice valueForKey:@"item"]` out as an `id`, then check what class it is. If it's not an `NSArray`, just wrap it in one before moving on to whatever "process" method you're calling.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
XMLReader.m

+(NSArray*)enforceArray:(id)payload{
    if ([payload isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
        return payload;
    }else{
        if ([payload isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || isEmpty(payload)) return [NSArray array];
        return [NSArray arrayWithObject:payload];
    }
}



//common.h
static inline BOOL isEmpty(id thing) {
    return thing == nil
    || [thing isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]
    || [thing respondsToSelector:@selector(isEqualToString)]
        && [(NSString*)thing isEqualToString:@"(null)"]
    || ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(length)]
        && [(NSData *)thing length] == 0)
    || ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(count)]
        && [(NSArray *)thing count] == 0);
}


 NSMutableArray *results  = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[XMLReader enforceArray:[[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"notifications"] objectForKey:@"notification"]]];
```

one day I'll dig through the core class to fix this at the root of problem. 
here's a bandaid in the mean time.